# Dynamic UIButton frame in iOS7

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have  a dynamic UITextView in a UITableViewCell. There is a button in each cell whose frame is set dynamically in accordance with the dynamic textView. The code written below works perfectly in the previous versions but is giving me a hard time in iOS7. This is my UITableViewCell's class. The button does not set it's frame in iOS7.

```
 - (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString     *)reuseIdentifier
{    
self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
if (self) {
    describeLabel = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 0, 290, 30)];
    describeLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [describeLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:10]];
    describeLabel.editable = NO;
    [self.contentView addSubview:describeLabel];

    button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [button setTitle:@"Apply Now" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    button.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:10];
    [button setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:29.0/255.0 green:96.0/255.0 blue:140.0/255.0 alpha:1.0] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.contentView addSubview:button];

}
return self;
}

-(void)updateData:(eServices*)data
{
describeLabel.text = data.eServicesdescription;
[describeLabel sizeToFit];
[describeLabel layoutIfNeeded];
button.frame = CGRectMake(230,height(describeLabel),60,30);

}
```

Any relevant help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Would be nice if you told us your problem.

Comment: My problem is that the Button does not set it's frame dynamically in iOS7